# How to call method from all opened forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I want call a method in the all opened forms

this code call MyUpdateFnc() on the last csutomer Opened Form:

```
if (Application.OpenForms["frmCustomer"] != null)
{
     (Application.OpenForms["frmCustomer"] as frmCustomer).MyUpdateFnc();
}
```

Several forms may be open.

Comment: since OpenForms is a collection, iterate it

Comment: How i can ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could get all forms of desired type using the `Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>` method. Next you need to iterate through the forms collection. For instance, using the `foreach` loop as follows:

```
foreach (frmCustomer frm in Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCustomer>())
    frm.MyUpdateFnc();
```

Comment: thanks. but Error 'System.Windows.Forms.FormCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method. what ?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the LINQ at the top of the file: `using System.Linq;`